# JS fade in elements (Moz issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two animations using JS to activate some css animation. Seems to be working fine in Chrome and Safari but not Moz. I havent tested in IE yet (since I am on my MBP) but sure that is borken too. Not sure why.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.background-image').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      });
    });
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#countries').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
    `@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      100% { opacity: 1; }
    }

    .background-image {
      background: url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;

      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;

     opacity: 0;

      -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    }

    .background-image.visible {
      opacity: 1;
    }
#countries{
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    left: 100px;
    top: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 

     opacity: 0;

      -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
      -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: .8;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
#countries.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Where are your `-moz` prefixed keyframe rules?

Comment: Could you share the `html snippet`?

Comment: You can use only one `$(document).ready` and wrap both handlers.

Comment: Thanks, spaced on the other keyframe rules, ha. But know working on the JS adding the 'visible' class to moz

Comment: @Adrift

 
So i added the other browser animation css to the file (totally spaced that) and the fade ins work but the JS is not adding the class visible to the Moz version. I added this to the JS `$(document).ready(function() { $('.background-image').on('mozAnimationEnd', function(e) { $(this).addClass('visible'); }); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using only vendor specific animation properties (webkit). Webkit is the browser engine for Chrome and Safari, so that's why it works.

Use the CSS property and vendor specific ones (see how and browser support): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation

Comment: So i added the other browser animation css to the file (totally spaced that) and the fade ins work but the JS is not adding the class visible to the Moz version. I added this to the JS $(document).ready(function() { $('.background-image').on('mozAnimationEnd', function(e) { $(this).addClass('visible'); }); });

Answer (score 0):

If you use [jQuery's Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method from start to finish, with all its effects (yes it even comes with the ability to show and hide items), you will have a healthier approach across browsers.  Example on the API page.

Comment: And if @Packy wants the benefit of CSS3 animations then the [jquery animate enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) plugin allows you to use the standard jQuery `.animate()` function and will convert the animations to CSS3 where compatible.